# How to check if the query returned result has changed since last check

Tags: php, mysql, caching

For caching purposes, I need to check whether `sql` returned set of data has changed. `HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE` will check if `the file code` has changed (correct me if I am wrong). I need a way to check if the `sql` returned results has changed? what's the best approach/way to do so? Thanx.

Comment: Check the `lastChange` row in your SQL result ;)

Comment: or possibly `max(lastChange)`

Comment: Hi @str and @Orangepill : could you elaborate? what the `lastChange` refer to? is it in a value returned by `MySQL`? please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to check whether sql returned set of data has changed

The real answer is: you can't :)

How can you tell that data has changed, when you did not check back? Correct - you just simply cannot tell!

Adjust your cache time according to *your* presumption, when the data *might* have changed. There is no easy way to decide this. Caching means to weigh up between how costly it is to fetch fresh data from the database and how long you (your users) can live with probably old data, and not every piece of data is as well cacheable as others.

The database itself uses query caches and should be able to serve an unchanged resultset from its cache (doing it *much* more intelligent as PHP could possibly do it). However, in a multiuser environment those caches tend to be freed early because of heavy database traffic. Here you can help out with your very own caching strategy.

Comment: The question is light on details, but HTTP conditional GET can save significant processing and data transfer time in some situation. Conditional updates are a neat way to avoid overwriting someone else's edits.

Answer (score 1):

u can use MD5(str);

```
if(md5($lastsql)==md5($nowsql)){}...
```

[md5 description](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/encryption-and-compression-functions/md5%28%29.php)

Comment: Hi, what `$lastsql` and `$nowsql` supposed to hold?

Comment: I think it should be if ($lastMD5 == md5(CONCAT_WS("_",FIELD1,FIELD2,...)))

Comment: where FIELDx are the relevant fields in the query. Albeit we do need to return the hash for the next comparison, and can even use it as the etag.

Answer (score 0):

> HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE will check if the file code has changed (correct me if I am wrong)

The `If-Modified-Since` header tells the application to respond with a `304` status code if it can determine that the resource hasn't changed since the specified date.

For static files, usually the web server handles this itself, and the modification date is the modification date of the static file.

For non static resources, like a PHP script, the application (i.e. your code) has to handle the If-Modified-Since header itself. Most applications don't. Applications implementing this usually refer to the modification of the data, not the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably doing "Optimistic Concurrency Control". This usually involves a "version" field in the database, which then you can use as the "etag" in HTTP. (the keyword there is "conditional GET")

Comment: The problem is that the query use more than one table, and I can update one or more than one table. Also tables are not updated via php. so maybe I should do a trigger. Long way to perform that.

Comment: Multiple tables: No problem, just combine their "version" fields to form the "etag". Other database users not participating in "optimistic locking": you can fall back to calculate the hash of all relevant fields and use that as the etag. MySQL has an "md5()" function you can use for this. Depending on the consequences of a one-in-a-2^128 chance of false positive, you can use this to generate "304 Not Modified" responses to conditional HTTP GETs, and perform conditional updates.